# ASP MVC Passing value into modal window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this view with a modal window. When I click to open the modal window, I'd like to pass the parameter `item.InstrumentId` into the modal window so that I can click on a link that redirects me to the page from that specific instrument that belongs to the InstrumentId. What I'm doing below successfully passes the InstrumentId into the window, but the problem is I don't know how to pass that value into the `Html.ActionLink`. Any hints as to how I can proceed?

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4>
                        Instrument: @item.InstrumentId
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @item.Type
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="open-dialog btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="@item.InstrumentId">
                        View details
                    </button>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function() {
                            var modalId = $(this).data('id');
                            $(".modal-dialog #myModal").val(modalId);
                        })
                    </script>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal"></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    @item.Message
                                    <br/> <br/> <br/>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            Slide: <a href="/Home/Slide" class="Button">1234500323</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            Instrument: @Html.ActionLink(item.InstrumentId, "Instrument", new {instrumentid = item.InstrumentId})
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            Checked: @item.Checked
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div>
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4>
                        Instrument: @item.InstrumentId
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @item.Type
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="open-dialog btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-url="@Url.Action("Instrument", new {instrumentid = @item.InstrumentId})">
                        View details
                    </button>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function() {
                            $('#details').attr('href', $(this).data('url')); // update the links url
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @*@item.Message*@
                <br /> <br /> <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Slide: <a href="/Home/Slide" class="Button">1234500323</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Instrument: <a id="details" href="#">Details</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Checked: @*@item.Checked*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your element with `id="myModal"` is `<h4>` so `$(".modal-dialog #myModal").val(modalId);` cannot possibly work despite what you claim.

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? And since  the `Html.ActionLink()` you already have  `new { instrumentid = item.InstrumentId }` why do you need to pass the same value to it that it already has?

Comment: Yes I'm doing this in a loop. The <h4> doesn't show anything, but if I put something like an <input> element in there, I can display the value in the modal window. 

Thing is, I have a of instruments. Each instrument has a button for viewing details about this instrument. The reason why I need to pass the value, is because I need to pass the id from the specific instrument I click on and item.InstrumentId only gets the first id from the first instrument in the list.

Comment: So the buttons are in a loop but the modal is not?

Comment: Well, everything is in the loop. I've updated the OP with the loop added.

Comment: The problem is that the modal is in a loop but you have invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. You should only have one model and pass the values to it. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently generating a modal for each item in your collection but giving it an `id="myModal"` which is invalid html and means `data-target="#myModal"` will only ever open the first one. Move the modal outside the loop so your create only one (and also remove the `<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal"></h4>` element which also has the same `id` attribute)

Then change the button html to

```
<button type="button" class=".." .. data-url="@Url.Action("Instrument", new { instrumentid = item.InstrumentId })">
```

and change the html in the modal to

```
Instrument: <a id="details" href="#">Details</a>
```

Then change the script to

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function() {
    $('#details').attr('href', $(this).data('url')); // update the links url
})
```

Side note: You will probably want to do something similar with `Checked: @item.Checked` in the modal

Comment: I've updated the code, but now it seems like the modal is not triggered when I click the button. I've updated the OP.

Comment: Firstly your update shows your script is not even inside `$(document).ready()` - so could not possibly work (but you should move it to the bottom of the page anyway). Secondly you have removed the `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` attributes - i just replaced it with `...` in my code so to highlight the imortant change :)

Comment: Oh boy, I feel like such a tool. You're right. It seems to be working now, and I've even learned a bunch on the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1.Use `ID` for Anchor Link.
2.Notice this line `<a href='#' id='InstrumentIDLink'>Anchor Link Value=</a>` in code. It has `Anchor Link Value=`. When you open modal you can see `Anchor Link Value=10320320` and you can inspect `href` too.

```js
$('#myModal1').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var modalId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  $('#InstrumentIDLink').attr('href', 'url+'+ modalId)
  $('#InstrumentIDLink').text('Anchor Link Value='+ modalId);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Modal Example</h3>
  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <div> <a href="#myModal1" class='open-dialog' role="button" 
           class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-id='10320320'>Launch Modal (10320320)</a><br/>
    <a href="#myModal1" class='open-dialog' role="button" 
           class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-id='10320321'>Launch Modal (10320321)</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> <a href='#' id='InstrumentIDLink'>Anchor Link Value=</a>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From bootstrap 3+ you can use `e.relatedTarget` to get element that triggered the modal

Answer (score 0):

Instrument:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link_Text", "Action_Name", "Controller_Name", new { id=item.InstrumentId})
```

Now in your COntroller you can access this value like

```
public ActionResult Action_Name(int id)
{
    //Do something
    return view();
}
```