# Pass a value to a modal, then to a controller's function

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, modal-dialog

It all starts with a loop, lets make it short :

```
foreach (var building in Model.CompanysBuildings)
{
    <a data-target="#AddRoom" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@building.id">Add room for this building</a>
}
```

It makes the modal appear :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AddRoom" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" >
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm add up</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            How many room do you wish to add ?<br /> 

            <input type="text" name="NumberOfRoomAdded" id="nbRoom">

            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenFieldOfModal" id="CompanysId" value="   ??????   ">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
            <button id="btnProceedAddRoom" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add this number of room</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the script for `btnProceedAddRoom` click, which will call a c# function in some controller (AddRoom, Admin) :

```
<script>

var numberOfRooms;
var idCompany;
$('#btnProceedAddRoom').click(function () {


    numberOfRooms = $("#nbRoom").val();

    idCompany = $("#CompanysId").val();


    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AddRoom", "Admin")",
        type: $("#ViewModelForm").attr('method'),
        data: $("#ViewModelForm").serialize() + "&noBloc=" + numberOfRooms + "&idCompany=" + idCompany
    }).done(function (result) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
});

</script>
```

The main problem is to retrieve the `data-id="@building.id"` in the modal part... Once I will be able to do that, there will be no problem passing it forth to the script part. I suppose this property could have this purpose, but how is it possible to retrieve a `data-id` in a modal ?

I tried to figure it out using this : [ASP MVC Passing value into modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714917/asp-mvc-passing-value-into-modal-window)

I could not make sens out of it... I would be extremely glad for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set `CompanysId` in the modal html, because the same modal will be used for multiple `<a data-target="#AddRoom" ... </a>` anchor tags. You have to set the `CompanyId` in the hidden field on the click event of the anchor tag. A quick and dirty solution can be:

```
<a data-target="#AddRoom" onclick="$('#CompanysId').val('@building.id');" data-toggle="modal" >Add room for this building</a>
```

Although the above code should work, I will suggest you to bind a function in the anchor tag's click event. In that function, read `CompanyId` from the anchor tag and assign that to the hidden field. Then programmatically show the modal.

Comment: I'd like to know why the dirty solution is that dirty, it seemed like much more simplicity. I don't see how it's dangerous in any way.